# TableView with custom cells. When cells scroll (deque) they reappear with mixed up UIView colours. Can I set UIView at indexPath.row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

// First subclass

```
class reportCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var repLabel: UILabel!
}
```

// Second subclass

```
class sectionCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secLabel: UILabel!
}
```

//

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if cellType == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellRep", for: indexPath) as! reportCell

        cell.repLabel?.text = type[indexPath.row]

        cell.view1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 25/255, green: 34/255, blue: 40/255, alpha: 1)


        return cell

    }

    if cellType == 1 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellSec", for: indexPath) as! sectionCell

        cell.secLabel?.text = type[indexPath.row]

        cell.view2.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 201/255, green: 113/255, blue: 91/255, alpha: 1)

        return cell

    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: How do you set `cellType`?

Comment: I set cellType during the button press. cellType = 1 or cellType = 0. Then I reload the table.

Comment: And if you don't press button, there aren't any bugs?

Comment: No all works fine except the table scrolls fine, the labels are correct as to my array  but the colours get mixed up. I will look how to put a screenshot on my post to show you.

Comment: Sorry it won't let me add images yet.

Comment: So I have 2 buttons. These add the relative cell. Each of the 2 cells has a UIView with a different colour in each. Blue for the first cell and Orange for the second cell. All this is fine. However when I scroll the table and the cells deque, then I scroll back to them the text is fine as it is assigned indexPath.row but the UIViews colours change. All turn blue.

Comment: Add this code of buttons' actions to question

Comment: you can add image on igmur, and link the image as comment

Comment: Now when I try and add more code to my post I get "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." As you c an tell I am new to Stackflow question asking...  Also can't add images until I have earned so many points or something !?

Comment: Basically my button does this. cellType = 1
    
        rows.append(1)
        
        type.append("Section")

Answer (score 0):

If your table has a static number of cells, you can add the colors in the desired sequence into an array and take at index indexPath.row from it. Something like this `let colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.yellow]     cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row]`

Comment: Yes I am sure I have tried this but my with my table there is no set pattern of colours so I can't call them from an array. If one button is pressed a blue coloured cell appears, the other an orange coloured cell appears.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, could not do what I wanted with UIView's. The views were not being reused at the correct indexPath.row. Remember I was randomly adding different cells with the press of a button. So I couldn't use a pattern format for colours in an array.

Ended up using UIImageViews in the colours I required. These are easily assigned to indexPath.row the same as labels.